# How to put a div outside the body?

Tags: html, css

Im putting a box using jQuery (show) on top of the page. I want the whole page to move down when it's showing, even the body background image which size is set to contain to be responsive. Since the div is placing itself inside the body tag, the background image wont place itself underneith the box.

How can I make the background image relative so it will be pushed down when box is showing?

```
body{
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333;
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(../images/SELFIE-first.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-position: top;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a wrapper div of some sort? Apply the background to a div that wraps your content. That div can then be pushed down taking the background with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put something outside of `<body>` tag.

You have to create a container `div` with all of your content and place the background to that div. Then your jquery box could be placed above that.